# Are there any books on how mathematicians reason about infinite sets?

Tags: infinity

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason*  (1st edn 2008)](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 457.

> 172. For an account of Ramanjuan and his ignorance of proofs, see Kanigel (1991, p. 92, and
>        see p. 207 for the comment quoted from the great Cambridge mathematician, G.H.
>        Hardy). With a finite number of finite models, we can always in principle determine
>        whether an inference is valid. Mathematicians, however, have to think about the positive integers, 1, 2, 3, . . . , and there are infinitely many of them. **How they reason about
>        infinite sets is a mystery**, which psychologists have yet to elucidate.

1. Is the emboldened phrase true? If yes, how and why? Mathematicians have been doing this for millenia?
2. If it isn't, please recommend books or papers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about mathematics education.

Comment: Be aware that even some theorems of "finite mathematics" may require a detour through the infinite, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50949/242) to the MSE question "Math without  infinity".

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche But a good answer clearly could be of great use in math eudcation, so one shouldn't be so quick to close. Why not be more constructive and help to reformulate the question to emphasize its pedagogical aspects?

Comment: A good answer to the question "Does convergence in measure imply almost everywhere convergence?" might also be useful to educators.  The problem is that, as stated, it isn't a question *about* mathematics education.  If you want to rephrase the question so that it actually focuses on the educational or pedagogical issues involved, I'll be the first to upvote.  Until then, I've voting to close.

Comment: I strongly suspect that nothing useful is going to be accomplished by applying a logical-microscope to comments made by someone who is almost certainly not very knowledgeable about mathematical practice, let alone very knowledgeable about the philosophy of mathematics. I say this as someone who just finished reading (takes about an hour) [**The World's Most Famous Math Problem**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0312106572) by Marilyn vos Savant (1993), and as I read this book, I constantly had to suppress my desire to "fix things" in the margins of my copy of the book.

Comment: I suspect that, when posed by psychologist, the words "How do we reason about the infinite?" is in fact asking a different _question_ than when asked by a mathematician. It may very well be a pedagogically valuable question, and probably won't be answered by "induction".

Comment: The notion of an infinite set is often introduced using Hilbert's Infinite Hotel Paradox https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel to develop the definition of an infinite set. From a PEDAGOGICAL perspective, it may be better to first nail down what we mean by a finite set as I do at my blog posting http://www.dcproof.com/Infinity.html  There, I start by introducing a non-numerical notion of a finite set. An infinite set then is one that is not finite.

Comment: @Dan Christensen: "*first nail down what we mean by a finite set*" --- Of possible interest to you is [What's between the finite and the infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608035/whats-between-the-finite-and-the-infinite) (especially follow the links in my comment to Cameron Buie's answer).

Comment: One accessible extensive account of how a set-theorist thinks about various facets of infinity is Rudy Rucker's popular book *Infinity and the Mind* - aimed at an educated layperson. You can find an except [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5390/242)

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Presumably the margin of the book is too small to contain your corrections?

Comment: If there was something like metamathematics site I would know what to do with this one. It doesn't belong to mathematics, because it doesn't address a mathematical problem and it is not solely about education of mathematics neither. OTOH it is probably interesting for both, mathematicians and math educators and I feel it being a tiny bit more appropriate for educators than pure math.